# can't take name of running jar

Tags: java, executable-jar

I know there are a lot of similar questions and answers. But no one solution work for me! I don't understand why((
So I have runnable jar for example 'program.jar' and inside of it I want to take name of this jar (namely program.jar). I've tried following:

- `ClassInsideJar.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()`
- `new  java.io.File(ClassInsideJar.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath())`
- `new File(".")).getAbsolutePath()` (and different variations like getCanonicalPath etc)
- `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath()`

And in all these cases I can take only path to this jar. For example full path is `J:/folder/program.jar`. All that I can see are `J:/folder`.

What's the mistake? I'm trying to get name of jar in main class and others.

I've tried to run this jar by double click and with command line. Result is the same

Comment: `ClassInsideJar.getResource("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF").toExternalForm()`? Should give `J:/folder/program.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

Comment: But it returns "rsrc:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"... Why?(

Comment: A java protocol handler for `rsrc:` evidently was used. This must be some proprietary ClassLoader thing; JarRsrcLoader or so. Maybe the calling class has loaded the jar specifically. Then it becomes not so obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(new File(ClassInsideJar.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI())).getName();
```

Comment: It's exception...
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
        at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: ClassInsideJar.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() return "rsrc:/"